# MongooseDB Node js population doesn't work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, populate

I have a tourSchema that I wanted to add *"reviews"* in it, so I added it virtually and I populated it in my *getTour* but it still shows *reviews* as an empty array.

**here's where I added reviews virtually**

```
tourSchema.virtual('reviews', {
 ref: 'Review',
 foreignField: 'tour', //I've added tour in my reviewSchema as well
 localField: '_id'
 });
```

**here's where I've populated reviews**

```
exports.getTour = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
const tour = await Tour.findById(req.params.id).populate('reviews')
if (!tour) {
  return next(new appError('No tour found with that ID', 404));
}
res.status(200).json({
  status: 'success',
  data: {
    tour
  }
  });
 });
```

Comment: What do you mean an empty array? like no objects? populate doesn't add objects to the array, it replaces the _id with the mongo document in DB